# Can only access some javascript object keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I am noticing strange behavior from a javascript object in my Node application. The `user` object is created by parsing a csv file with two columns: `Email` and `ID`. For some reason, I can only access one of the fields using the typical methods. The other field always returns undefined. I am using Node 15.12.0.

When I log the `user` object, it returns: `{ 'Email': 'email@example.com', ID: '12345' }`

Curiously, the `ID` field does not have quotes when it is logged, but the `Email` field does have quotes.

I can access `user.ID` as usual, but `user.Email` returns `undefined`.

```
console.log(Object.keys(user)); // [ 'Email', 'ID' ]

console.log(user.ID); // 12345
console.log(user.Email); // undefined

console.log(user['Email']) // undefined
console.log(user["Email"]) // undefined
console.log(user.email) // undefined
console.log(user["\'Email\'"]) // undefined
console.log(user["'Email'"]) // undefined

console.log(user[Object.keys(user)[0]]) // email@example.com
console.log(Object.values(user)[0]) // email@example.com
```

I have tried the using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)), but I get the same results as before.

The only way I can access the `Email` field is by using the `user[Object.keys(user)[0]]` or `Object.values(user)[0]` which is very strange to me.

I would appreciate any ideas you have to figure out whats happening here. Is there something I can do to examine the object more closely? Does the quotes around the keys indicate anything?

Comment: My guess is there is some sort of hidden character in the text.  `console.log(Object.keys(user).map(x => escape(x)));`

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is the problem.